# AWS SDK runinstance and IAM roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, amazon-iam

The code below works when I have added the AWS IAM role "AdministratorAccess" - But it is risky and a bit of overkill... But how do I know and find only the necessary role(s)...It is very confusing and hard to know by when I look at all the possible roles in the console?

```
try {

            // Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
            var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

            // Set the region
            AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-2'});

            var instanceParams = {
                ImageId: 'ami-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
                InstanceType: 't2.micro',
                KeyName: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
                SecurityGroups: ['xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'],
                MinCount: 1,
                MaxCount: 1
            };

            // Create a promise on an EC2 service object
            var instancePromise = new AWS.EC2({apiVersion: '2016-11-15'}).runInstances(instanceParams).promise();

            // Handle promise's fulfilled/rejected states
            instancePromise.then(
                function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    var instanceId = data.Instances[0].InstanceId;
                    console.log("Created instance", instanceId);
                    // Add tags to the instance
                    var tagParams = {
                        Resources: [instanceId], Tags: [
                            {
                                Key: 'Name',
                                Value: 'SDK Sample'
                            }
                        ]
                    };

                    // Create a promise on an EC2 service object
                    var tagPromise = new AWS.EC2({apiVersion: '2016-11-15'}).createTags(tagParams).promise();
                    // Handle promise's fulfilled/rejected states
                    tagPromise.then(
                        function (data) {
                            console.log("Instance tagged");
                        }).catch(
                        function (err) {
                            console.error(err, err.stack);
                        });
                }).catch(
                function (err) {
                    console.error(err, err.stack);
                });
        }
        catch(e){
            wl.info('Error: ' + e);
        }
```

Comment: The recommended best practice is to create an IAM role with necessary permissions added in the IAM role's policies. In your case, you need `ec2:RunInstances` and `ec2:CreateTags`.

Comment: Okay - but how do I add roles? When I search for "RunInstances" or "CreateTags"when I am logged in AWS console, nothing shows up...? Do I have to create/add a custom rule or what? And how did you know the names/roles of what to add?

Comment: Note that you can supply tags in the runInstances() call so, strictly speaking, you do not need to use a separate createTags() call.

Comment: For help building IAM policies for managing EC2, see the examples at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ExamplePolicies_EC2.html#iam-example-instances, and more generally see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policies-for-amazon-ec2.html.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can see the api's you are calling via the sdk as a hint to what permissions you need i.e ec2:RunInstance and ec2:CreateTags.

You first create a policy then select the service then attach permissions (RunInstances and CreateTags)

You then create a Role with that policy attached.

Then you can attach the role to your Lambda